# Multiple short tasks

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

What is the best approach to handle multiple short-time tasks?

I have a case where I need to work off a lot of short-time/cheap `Action`s. The number can vary from let's say 8 to 100 and the time each action needs is between 0.00x ms and 1 ms. Because it's for UI the work should done in 60fps. But I will also run the code on Xamarin and low-end mobiles, so that goal cannot be reached always, that's why I'm using `Task`s.
Actually I'm using a custom TaskScheduler from [here](https://psycodedeveloper.wordpress.com/2013/06/28/a-custom-taskscheduler-in-c/).

Now, the question is, how to handle all these actions:

How expensive is `Task.Run`/`Task.Factory.StartNew`?

Would it be better to collect the multiple actions in a `ConcurrentQueue` and starting just max. 4 tasks (on a 4 core CPU) that will work off all the actions in while loop until queue is empty?

Are multiple tasks managed by TaskScheduler much more expensive than multiple actions in a single (or some few) task(s)?

I would like to take advantage of the existing async/await TPL structure, but is it also good for many and very small/short/cheap Actions?

Comment: For such short tasks it might be even faster to run them sequentially (at least on the lower bound, when there are just 8). But all this should be measured.

Comment: I thought about that too, but for that I would need to estimate the afford of the workload of each of these 8 (or more). Until now I tried to avoid that because of the complexity of the data structure it wouldn't be easy to implement and also it would cost extra computing time. Difficult decision...
But, you're right: That all should be measured.

Comment: @Evk: Isn't the relevance of synchronous code based on the _very short runtime_ of the tasks, as opposed to how many tasks there are?

Comment: @Flater sure, I just based my comment on "60 FPS" requirement. If there are 8 tasks, they will take at most 8ms in this case, which still fits in 60 FPS.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best approach would be to use Parallel.Invoke().  This has lower overhead than creating Tasks.  It will also automatically determine how many actions to run simultaneously, depending on the current hardware.

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-use-parallel-invoke-to-execute-parallel-operations) for more details.

I have tried this with thousands of Tasks and Parallel.Invoke is faster.

Comment: I wasn't aware of Parallel.Invoke(). Sounds good. Thanks for the hint! I will try this out.

Comment: Issue I find with Parallel APIs is their ability take over almost all control from the developer, impacting the system scalability, even when there's a scope it will not scale up, especially for managing the http calls. Also its a blocking call.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj, it is its purpose to take over the control from the developer.  As I wrote, it takes care to scale on all available hardware resources.  If you need a finer level of control, you can write your own TaskScheduler, but the overhead of tasks (if thousands) will drag you down.

As for being a blocking call, it is pretty easy to avoid it using a long-running task.  And it must be a long-running one, because otherwise you're exhausting a thread from the thread-pool, which otherwise will be available to serve your Parallel.Invoke().

Comment: @Nick, this part is incorrect, it is an assumption, "it takes care to scale on all available hardware resources", for high load from single client set up, I have seen Parallel API heavily throttling the request pipeline, also internally it use the same thread pool as Task API, just that Task provides little more fine grain control. Rewriting Task Scheduler is not the only way, using Task parallelism is preferred to Parallel API

Comment: @MrinalKamboj, Task API has more overhead than Parallel.Invoke().  I had a benchmark for small computational tasks, where the overhead of creating tasks costs more than Parallel.Invoke().  Well, that is why we need to benchmark all the time. :-)